# Updating Picker on update of ObservedObject

Tags: swift, picker

I'm trying up dynamically add new rows to a `Picker` as follows:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {    
    @Published private (set) var drinks = ["Tea", "Coffee", "Wine"]

    func addDrink(_ drink: String) {
        drinks.append(drink)
    }
}

struct PickerTest: View {

    @State private var selectedDrink = "Tea"
    @State private var customDrink = ""
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a drink", text: $customDrink)
                Spacer()
                Button("Add") {
                    self.viewModel.addDrink(self.customDrink)
                }
            }
            Picker("Drinks", selection: $selectedDrink) {  // Removing the wrapping Picker works
                ForEach(viewModel.drinks, id: \.self) { drink in
                    Text(drink)
                }
            }
        }.padding().labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. If I remove the `Picker` wrapping the `ForEach`, the `ForEach` updates as expected.

Is there a way to update the `Picker` dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Picker`s bug - I hope, that Apple fixes it in future releases of SwiftUI.

I found **ugly** (I really don't like it) workaround for this problem:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDrink = "Tea"
    @Published var drinks = ["Tea", "Coffee", "Wine"]
    @Published var drinksChanged = true

    func addDrink(_ drink: String) {
        drinks.append(drink)
        drinksChanged.toggle()
    }
}

struct DrinksPicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Drinks", selection: $viewModel.selectedDrink) {
            ForEach(viewModel.drinks, id: \.self) { drink in
                Text(drink)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PickerTest: View {
    @State private var customDrink = ""
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a drink", text: $customDrink)
                Spacer()
                Button("Add") {
                    self.viewModel.addDrink(self.customDrink)
                    self.customDrink = ""
                }
            }
            if viewModel.drinksChanged {
                DrinksPicker(viewModel: viewModel)
            } else {
                DrinksPicker(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
        }.padding().labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

You can also hide this `if`-`else` in some another container:

```
struct DrinksPickerContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.drinksChanged {
                DrinksPicker(viewModel: viewModel)
            } else {
                DrinksPicker(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then use only `DrinksPickerContainer(viewModel: viewModel)` in `PickerTest`

Comment: Thanks - not ideal, but it'll have to do for now I guess.